# How to pass an ADO Recordset (or any COM object) across thread boundaries?

Tags: delphi, com, ado

i have an ADO `Recordset` object that is created in a background thread:

```
var
   conn: TADOConnection;
   rs: _Recordset;
begin
   conn := CreateDatabaseConnection();
   rs := conn.Execute(CommandText, cmdText, []);
   conn.Free;

   //Give the recordset to the UI thread
   //Don't forget to add a reference before we stuff it into a 32-bit variable
   rs._AddRef();
   PostMessage(hwndUIThreadWindow, WM_HeresTheRecordsetYouAskedFor, WPARAM(rs), 0);
end;
```

And then the `Recordset` is handed to my *"main"* thread:

```
procedure ExecuteComplete(var msg: TMessage); message WM_HeresTheRecordsetYouAskedFor;
var
   rs: _Recordset;    
begin
   rs := _Recordset(msg.wParam);
   //don't forget to remove the manually added reference
   rs._Release();

   ShowMessage(rs.Fields['TheTimeIs'].Value);
end;
```

i also could have done:

```
var 
   global_Recordset: _Recordset;

var
   conn: TADOConnection;
begin
   conn := CreateDatabaseConnection();
   global_Recordset := conn.Execute(CommandText, cmdText, []);
   conn.Free;
end;
```

Either way, a thread that **didn't** create the COM object is now using it. From the **main** thread:

```
global_Recordset .Fields['TheTimeIs'].Value;
```

COM forbids accessing COM objects from apartments (in this case: *threads*) that did not create the object.

What is the *correct* way to marshal in *in-process* COM object interfaces across apartment boundaries?

Comment: Not really an answer but look a little bit further and pass the data you want, NOT the COM object...

Comment: @whosrdaddy sounds like a good answer to me.

Comment: @whosrdaddy Imagine i've stored my data an interfaced variable. Same question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to pass a COM object across apartments is to marshal the interface pointer, which can be done in one of two different ways:

1. Have the worker thread call the [`CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693316.aspx) function and pass the resulting `IStream` pointer to the UI thread, which then calls the [`CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691421.aspx) function.
2. Use the [`IGlobalInterfaceTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678517.aspx) interface.  Have the worker thread create the interface and call its `RegisterInterfaceInGlobal()` method and pass the resulting cookie to the UI thread, which then creates the interface and calls its `GetInterfaceFromGlobal()` and `RevokeInterfaceFromGlobal()` methods.

Comment: Adding a note these solutions only work for apartments in the same process, and cannot be used in the general case to marshal an interfaces across apartments.